# Code Igniter Ion Auth: Where are the email templates?

Tags: codeigniter, ion-auth

I'm working with both Code Igniter and Ion Auth for the first time. I'd like to change the language in the Ion Auth email templates (password reset, email verification, etc).

This is what appears to be the password reset email template (forgot_password.tpl.php), but I'm not sure where things like 'email_forgot_password_subheading' and 'email_forgot_password_heading' are defined. A Windows search of my local installation doesn't bring up any results. Can you help?

```
<html>
<body>
<h1><?php echo sprintf(lang('email_forgot_password_heading'), $identity);?></h1>
<p><?php echo sprintf(lang('email_forgot_password_subheading'),
anchor('auth/reset_password/'. $forgotten_password_code,    
lang('email_forgot_password_link')));?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those will be in the language file in `application/language/english/ion_auth_lang.php`